# Prove that every ray is a polyhedron

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra

I am reading a book on linear optimization and I am stuck with the following problem:

> Prove that every ray in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron.

The book defines a ray as follows:

> For a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector $d\in\mathbb{R}^n$, a ray is the set $$\{x_0+\lambda d \mid \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{such that} \, \lambda \ge 0\}$$

It also defines a polyhedron as a set of solutions to a system of linear inequalities.

My idea is to find a linear transformation $A$, whose kernel is the subspace spanned by $d$. Consequently, the set of solutions to the equation $Ax=Ax_0$ will be a line containing the ray. But there is two problems. First I do not know how to find such a $A$. Second, I do not know what to do next.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure a polyhedron isn't defined as the solution set of a *system* of linear inequalities, rather than just one linear inequality? Because all you get from one inequality is half-spaces.

Comment: @coffeemath Actually the book uses the vector inequality notation but I will edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: @coffeemath By vector notation, I mean $Ax\le b$ where $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ and $b$ are both $n$-dimensional vectors. The inequality means that every component of $Ax$ is less than the corresponding component of $b$. So I believe that this is equivalent to a system of linear inequalities. It also is equivalent to the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces. Hence it determines a polyhedron in all three definitions.

Comment: I am pretty sure a set of linear inequalities can only give you _convex_ polyhedra.

Comment: @Arthur The book considers polyhedra as a subset of convex sets.

Comment: Ok, then that's fine. I'm just used to polyhedra not necessarily being convex as an implicit assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the ray be $R= \{x_0+t d \}_{t \ge 0}$. Let $d_2,...,d_n$ be a basis for $\{ d \}^\bot$, then
$R = \{ x | d_k^T(x-x_0) = 0, d^T(x-x_0) \ge 0\}$.